# Trying to create a regex that allowes following format yyyy[: -][VW]Week number

Tags: regex

My regex currently looks like this

```
\b(19|20)\d{2}\b[- :][VW][0-5]{1}(?(?=[5])[0-2]{1}|[0-9]{1})
```

It doesn't quite do what I want as I'm trying to get this part

```
(?(?=[5])[0-2]{1}|[0-9]{1})
```

to say "If the previous number was 5 then you may only choose between 0-2, and if it's another number 0-4 then choosing between 0-9 is allowed

Currently it allowes 00-59 with an exclusion of 05,15,25,35 etc.

Essentially I want it to look like this for example 2016-W25.

Comment: Week 53 exists some years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace `[5]` with a positive lookbehind `(?<=5)` in order to check a char *to the left* of the current location:

```
\b(19|20)\d{2}[- :][VW][0-5](?(?=(?<=5))[0-2]|[0-9])
                                  ^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vD7rU5/1)

Also, you may get rid of the conditional pattern at all using a mere alternation group:

```
\b(19|20)\d{2}[- :][VW](?:[0-4][0-9]|5[0-2])
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See  [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lZ0cL8/1)

The `(?:[0-4][0-9]|5[0-2])` matches either a digit from `0` to `4` and then any digit (see `[0-4][0-9]`), or (see `|`) a `5` followed with `0`, `1` or `2` (see `5[0-2]`).

**NOTE**: Since the number of weeks can amount to 53, the `[0-2]` at the end might be replaced with `[0-3]` to also match `53` values.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help, it works fine with that addition. I'll mark it as the answer in 9 min when I'm allowed

Comment: Glad to help, please also check if you need a `\b` at the end of the pattern. As for Week 53, you can fix that by replacing `[0-2]` with `[0-3]`.

Comment: Out of scope of this question/answer, but (at least in Sweden) week numbers can go up to 53 ;)

Comment: @ClasG: Do you think the regex in the answer must be changed to `\b(19|20)\d{2}[- :][VW](?:[0-4][0-9]|5[0-3])`?

Comment: I guess that depends on the application and is up to OP.

Comment: @ClasG I did not think of that... I will have to review how I can make the system I built so far work for those cases. I think there's 5 years until the next one or so...

Comment: Ok, I added a note at the bottom.